# When is the constant coefficient $a_{0}$ of the Taylor series of $f(x)$ zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f(x)$ and its Taylor series centered at $c$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}(x-c)^{n}}$. For what value of $c$ is $a_{0}=0$?

I suspect if $a_{0}=0$, then $c$ is a root of the function $f(x)$.

Comment: I believe when 'c' is the root of f(x) then putting x=c on both sides implies a$_{0}$ = 0.

Comment: You started with "a function $f(x)$" and then finished with "the polynomial $f(x)$".  Note that a Taylor *series* (as shown in your Question's first line) is a generalization of a polynomial.  Please clarify the assumptions on $f(x)$, and adjust the title accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by $a_0$?? Was $\sum_{n-0}^\infty(x-c)^n$ supposed to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$???

Comment: I fixed it.. Sorry about that..

Comment: $f(c) =a_0$ as all other terms for $n\ge 1$ vanish for $x=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor expansion centered at $x_0$ of a function $f(x)$ is (note you did not get this formula right when posing the question):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

Where $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ means the nth-derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at point $x_0$. Thus, the constant term in the expansion is just given by the function evaluated at the point $x_0$ i.e. $a_0=f(x_0)$, but of course this vanishes if $x_0$ is a root of $f(x)$.

Therefore we conclude that the constant term $a_0$ is absent if and only if the expasion is centered around a root of $f(x)$.